# Timed out waiting for device /sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmbus!hv_kvp (20.04, Hyper-V related?)

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, kernel, hyper-v

I have an ubuntu-20.4 machine. An hour ago I decided to reboot the computer because a simulator was hung and I knew I have to install ubuntu software update(to do it after reboot). So I gave a reboot command `sudo shutdown -r now` hoping the simlator gracefully being killed(?) could send some message to the license server releasing the simulator license.
Anyway, after the boot, my machine's console has just a blinking cursor at the top left corner. Alt-F2(tty2)  and Alt-F3(tty3) work and I can login there. I can even start vnc server and use vnc window from my windows 10 machine as usual. `uname -r` gives me 5.13.0-35-generic, so I removed `quiet splash` from the boot command line in /boot/grub/grub.confg for /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-35-generic. When I reboot the computer, I see these two lines at the end and no progress.

```
Timed out waiting for device /sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmbus!hv_kvp
Dependency failed for Hyper-V kVP Protocol Daemon.
```

What is this problem? and How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember how I sollved it. My work note sayhs about the incident but continues as if nothing happend. So maybe I rebooted? I sometimes regret not recording things correctly. Sorry it doesn't help.